# Standards for Git expertise, how to express it on CV

Tags: software-industry

What are the commonly-accepted forms of expressing Git expertise on a CV?

I feel like someone who is extremely proficient in Git including the terrifying deserted depths of rebasing, submodules, filter-branch, etc., is more attractive an employee, all else equal, than someone who has only ever been a `git pull` `git add` `git push` user.

How can someone express or prove their Git mastery on their CV?

Comment: In that respect, expertise in Git is really no different from expertise in any other technology.

Comment: git isn't _that_ important... most of the time pull/add/push is all you need

Comment: @FábioDias `git commit` is pretty important as well

Comment: Respectfully, if someone spent a lot of time laying out their git “mastery” in a CV I’d assume they didn’t have their priorities straight. Not in the sense that knowing git isn’t useful, but in the sense that it’s just not particularly impressive and I’d wonder why a candidate would spend effort highlighting it.

Comment: @cubic that's why I'm interested in how it might be possible to just put a bullet point "Git [_expertise_]" instead of spending time rambling about it like a weirdo

Comment: @theonlygusti I think you are overestimating how much people care about "advanced" git skills. Find something more important to put in that space of your CV instead.

Comment: The most important part of git is understanding the various steps that a file goes through -  including staging and the local repository - before it becomes available to others.

Comment: @Cubic Any deficiency in Git is a simple man page or Google search away. If you have any experience working on anything new, it's a honed process and there's just no point going into too much details.

Comment: Store your CV on Github and have a revision history that shows you did all sorts of complicated merges, rebases etc on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What are the commonly-accepted forms of expressing Git expertise on a CV?

There aren't any.

> How can someone express or prove their Git mastery on their CV?

How can you express it: "Highly experienced with Git, including advanced features such as rebasing and filtering".

How you can prove it: you can't. CVs never prove anything, they're just a set of claims.

Answer (score 5):

I would challenge the premise of your question.  I do not find the "depths" of Git use that unusual or challenging and wouldn't really think that much of someone's having familiarity with them.  And besides that, most fancy operations only need be done once in a while, and it is totally reasonable to resort to looking up how to do filter-branch operations, or check the reflog to undo a rebase, or whatever, on the rare occasions you need to.  If anything, a resume that was at pains to emphasize to me that the user had above-average Git skills would give the impression of the applicant lacking other, more relevant skills, and trying to paper over that issue with fluff.

Answer (score 3):

> "What are the commonly-accepted forms of expressing Git expertise on a CV?"

Though `Git` is perceived as a given anyway  when working in software-developement since it's  first release in 2005 (extending existing [CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) functionalities), if you really want to emphasise that in your CV you could rephrase your expertise into something along the lines of:

*"Expertise with best practice in source-code management, version-control and collaborative source-code development."*

> "How can someone express or prove their Git mastery on their CV?"

Expressing your git-mastery (or proving it) is going to be tricky as it would require and occupy at least a paragraph or two in your CV (normally 2-3 pages max) explaining your best practice efforts.

As I said above, being familiar with `pushing`, `pulling`, `branching`, `rebasing`, `cloning` and `merging` is expected anyway and actually isn't such a difficult task, so elaborating on it might take away the focus on your other (more important) IT-skills.

Comment: "Though Git is perceived as a given anyway when working in software-developement," - is that true? I certainly hadn't really used it before my current job.

Comment: @mattfreake It’s considered kind-of a given in huge sections of the industry because it’s become the default VCS to use if there aren’t any compelling reason to use something else. Also, pretty much 99.99% of open source projects these days use git, and the ones that don’t tend to be run by people who’ve written their own VCS. I wouldn’t be too shocked if someone didn’t know git, but it _is_ telling me something about how much that person engages in software outside of work.

Comment: @mattfreake Not for a complete newbie that just started in the IT-industry (i.E. intern, first time junior without CS-diploma etc.),  but I personally would assume anyone working in this field with more than a year of experience should have come across git IMO.. - but that's just my 2 cents ;)

Comment: I have been working in the industry for about 32 years now, and have still never used Git.

Comment: @SimonB Are you using some other VCS?

Comment: @iLuvLogix We're still using Subversion.  Yes, it's a bit old, but it's what we use, and migrating every project would be a significant effort.

Comment: @SimonB Ahh apache's SVN, that brings back some memories ;) We had our own server running 24/7 (on ubuntu) in our office - a bit loud but I guess it got the job done back then..

Answer (score 1):

Git is these days becoming much like an operating system.  Regardless of what you do, you need to use it as part of your job.

So unless you know much, much more than what is needed to clone, pull, push and merge in your favorite IDE's, from the command line, and on the web (github/gitlab/etc), I would personally just say something like "Use git on a daily basis".

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like someone who is extremely proficient in Git including the terrifying deserted depths of rebasing, submodules, filter-branch, etc., is more attractive an employee, all else equal, than someone who has only ever been a git pull git add git push user.

I like the other answers here as well on how to display it on your CV.

Most people would agree that git is simply an internal tool. At the end of the day using git won't make them any money but it will better help organize, review, and publish code.

With that said, I think the average person probably wouldn't be too thrilled with your git skills as much as the more relevant skills to the job. So with that said, I wouldn't really stress the points. Just mention you are very familiar with git and you understand the more advanced concepts. The interviewer would probably move on to the next questions after that.